# Laravel throws 404 when i visit the site

Tags: php, content-management-system, http-status-code-404, laravel

ive installed PongoCMS on Laravel framework and cofigured evrything ( like shown on pongocms.com guide ) but the thing is when i finish `cms::setup` and navigate to site url (Http://localhost/laravel/public ) it throws me 404 on the other side i can perfectly fine log in to dashboard and do evrything.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Setting `'index' => ''` in application/config/application.php fixed it for me.

Comment: actualy that wasnt the problem, CMS had a bug with the Windows enviroment i downloaded updated version ..and it did work for me

Comment: You could have answered your question and closed it then ;)